# Host and Vmware Different Vpn & Proxy connection

Tags: vmware

I want to open different vpn one for pc and one for virtual xp pro.

Example :
One game allow to connect only one pc from the modem.When I try connect both of them at the same time.One of them is failing because of multiple connecting.But when I open multiple Vpn and share one vpn in my host for Vmware maybe it is posible to connect two systems to the game :)

The solution is maybe to use in Vmware proxy but I have no idea :)
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the vpn part how you want to achieve that but the way out for any virtual machines is to have the machines use a bridged network where the machine acts as if it is running in the [setting up a briged vimware][1]

[1]: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html this means the vmware machine acts independent of the host in the network. It will have its own IP settings.

Comment: I understand you, make it sense when IP is different I think they can cath me I will try tonight and update my comment for the result :)

Comment: Cool hope it helps out.